# Ubuntu on a new HDD?

Tags: system-installation

Is there anyway possible to install Ubuntu on a new, blank hard drive, if yes can someone please tell me how?

My laptop broke and after I bought a new HDD which is a 2.5 SATA, I've asked people that I know who can provide me with a copy of windows 7 but none of them can, so I would like to get this OS on my laptop for some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download iso image completly free on a running computer from here:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

burn the iso on empty <s>CD</s> DVD, or create a bootable USB stick :

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

after that is easy install:

Regards,

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Note, Ubuntu does not fit into a CD anymore. You will need a DVD or at least 1GB USB flash drive.

Comment: Im no computer guy so can you please tell me what can i use to burn the ISO, and what is the ISO? :/ ... i have got a 4.7GB dvd i could use

Comment: I found this great site, here you can find out everything about burning, regardless of the OS you are using https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto

Answer (score 1):

This should not be any special case unless I'm missing something. 2.5 inch SATA should fit into your laptop and you should be able to boot it (assuming laptop is not completely broke.) Then simply pop-in your Ubuntu CD and install.

Note: You may have to choose "CD" as first media in bios settings.

Also choose "Use entire disk" during installation. Ubuntu will take care of partitioning for you. 
[Here's a useful link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop)!

Comment: Thanks but do i have to buy the ubuntu CD? or can i get it for free?

Comment: Note Ubuntu doe snot fit into a CD anymore. You will need a blank DVD or a blank 1GB or more flash drive.

Comment: Ubuntu is free, but you can voluntarily donate before download. Then burn it on DVD or USB stick.

Comment: Because Ubuntu, like most distros, is free for anybody to distribute, many companies will sell it on disc for a nominal fee like $5, just to cover their own costs.  Back in the dark ages when there were computer clubs and computer swap meets, people used to swap them or give them away cheap or free.  Nowadays you still occasionally see them as free DVDs with computer magazines.  But now, almost everyone has access to some other internet-connected PC and can just load it onto a DVD or USB stick from there.  This is probably a safer method too.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a normal installation, pretty much just google "how to install ubuntu". Just boot the cd, select "install now", select "use entire disk" and then just follow the prompts. BTW, Welcome to Linux!

Answer (score 1):

If you swap old and new drives in your laptop you will be done with installation easily like a charm.

However if you add new drive as a second one, then pay attention  what drive/partition you install to. Especially take into account that in case of two physical drives you will need to consider what is the best of the drives to keep GRUB boot loader.

Because when it is placed on the different from new Ubuntu holding drive you would have some issues if you later would like to disconnect a drive containing MBR.